# Python Flask Gunicorn Nginx HTTPS

Tags: python, nginx, flask, https, gunicorn

I just cannot get my application to run on https/ssl. I'm running my app with gunicorn, with the following command: `gunicorn --worker-class eventlet --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`
It works fine on http, but I don't know how to make my server (with port 5000) to run with https/ssl.

My Nginx sites-available file:

```
upstream websocket1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cervinare.se www.cervinare.se;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/cervinare.se/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        # include uwsgi_params;
        # uwsgi_pass unix:/root/cervinare-2/backend/cervinare.se.sock;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/api;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
        proxy_pass http://websocket1/socket.io;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cervinare.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cervinare.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

It's the /api/ route that I want to be https.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: your `/api/` `proxy_pass` should be `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api;`

Comment: @911 Yeah, sorry. I am trying everything to get https to work and forgot to change it back to 127.0.0.1. But it still wont work with https. :(